# Setting keyboard bindings in ace editor

Tags: key-bindings, ace-editor

I am trying to figure out how to set keyboard bindings in ace editor to vscode key bindings. I can see in the CDN that there is a vscode keybinding file available I just don't know how to set it.

I have tried:

```
editor.setKeyboardHandler("ace/keybinding/vscode");
```

And not surprisingly it did not work. I searched through docs to see if I can find anything and I have exhausted my search options. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct id is `"ace/keyboard/vscode"`, see the following snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit(null, {
    value: "test ctrl-D \n test",
    mode: "ace/mode/javascript"
  });
  editor.container.style.height = "100px";
  document.body.append(editor.container);
  editor.setKeyboardHandler("ace/keyboard/vscode");
</script>
```